# AngularJS directive using templateURL loaded template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a directive which would dynamically add content of template into DOM. Just like angular-datePicker does.

I would like to have such a directive as an attribute directive. I would use it for example for button. When button is clicked, form shows up. 
Technically I was thinking about using link function, binding a callback to element onClick event and add template content inside that callback using element.insertAfter method.

Problem is, I don't have access to template loaded by templateURL. And second problem is default behaviour of attribute directive - it automatically appends template as a child of the element. Is there any way how to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a little more custom behavior, and this is totally easy to script within your directive.

Basic steps:

1. fetch the template using the $http service
2. [compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) the template - referencing scope
3. insert template wherever you want into the DOM

   ```
   angular.module('myModule').directive('myDirective', function ($http, $compile) {
       var directive = {};

       directive.restrict = 'A';
       directive.link = function (scope, elem, attr) {
           var templateString = '';

           $http.get('[ path to template ]').then(function (response) {
               templateString = response.data;

               var compiledHtml = $compile(templateString)(scope); // compile with scope variables

               element.append(compiledHtml); // change this around to insert your element into the DOM
           });

       };

       return directive;
   });
   ```